# Prove $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Define multiplication in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ by $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$ and $f$ by $f(a+bi)=(a,b)$. To show $f$ is an isomorphism, it would suffice to show that $f$ is a bijection and a homomorphism.

I am easily able to show that f is a bijection. However, showing that f is a homomorphism is giving me some trouble. I can see that

$f((a+bi)+(c+di))=f((a+c)+(b+d)i)=(a+c,b+d)=(a,b)+(c,d)=f(a + bi)+f(c+di)$

however,

$f((a+bi)(c+di))=f(ac+adi+bci-bd)=f((ac-bd)+(ad+bc))=(ac-bd,ad+bc) \neq (ac,bd)$.

Where am I going wrong here?

Also, another thing I've noticed - If $f$ is an isomorphism, then the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{C}$ should be mapped to the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. But $1+0i=1$ is the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f(1)=(1,0)$. This isn't the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ because $(1,1)$ is!

How can $f$ possibly be an isomorphism?

I'm sure my logic is wrong in at least one place. Any critiques are appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think $f$ should be an isomorphism?

Comment: Perhaps this is a poor reason, but I see this post https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120325172144AAewdr7

Comment: That link says that they are isomorphic as additive groups, not as rings.

Comment: Ah, I'm a dummy. Does my logic check out here then?

Comment: Note that one of them is a field whereas the other is not even an integral domain.

Comment: The ring $\Bbb R^2$ has zero divisors, but $\Bbb C$ doesn't. The ring $\Bbb R^2$ has four idempotents, whereas $\Bbb C$ only has two. The ring $\Bbb R^2$ has two proper nontrivial ideals ($\Bbb R\times0$ and $0\times\Bbb R$) while $\Bbb C$ has none. The ring $\Bbb R^2$ has four square roots of its multiplicative identity, whereas $\Bbb C$ only has two. The ring $\Bbb C$ has a square root of its multiplicative identity's additive inverse, whereas $\Bbb R^2$ doesn't. So no, they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you! Are all of these reasons sufficient for disproving an isomorphism? So far I've learned that you can show that f is not a bijection, not a homomorphism, the 2 rings have a different number of zero divisors, or that the 2 rings have a different number of units. The ones you mentioned are new to me.